# Join two files with different fields number

Tags: text-processing, columns, join

I have two files:
s2.txt

```
14 3KC12828ACBA 
43 8DG59242BAAD 
25 8DG60566AAAF 
6 8DG60912AAAF
```

and pbas.txt:

```
3AG33662AAAC
3KC12828ACBA
8DG59242BAAD
8DG60349AAAC
8DG60565AAAG
8DG60566AAAF
8DG60568AAAC
8DG60912AAAF
8DG62635AAAC
```

Using bash on UNIX I want to join files in order to obtain one file like that:

```
3AG33662AAAC
3KC12828ACBA 14
8DG59242BAAD 43
8DG60349AAAC
8DG60565AAAG
8DG60566AAAF 25
8DG60568AAAC
8DG60912AAAF 6
8DG62635AAAC
```

How can make that?

Answer (score 10):

That's what `join` does:

```
join -2 2 -a 1 pbas.txt s2.txt
```

The options say:

- `-2 2`: the second file uses the second column to store the key
- `-a 1`: output all lines from file 1, even if there's no match in file 2.

Comment: @costica_p, please read https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Interesting is that not works for me because one of files have terminator line  windows type (LF/CR) an other have unix type. After change to unix type for both files everything is perfect.

Answer (score 2):

#### AWK

It's fairly easy to achieve this in awk:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$1; next}{print $1,a[$1]}' file1.txt file2.txt    
3AG33662AAAC
3KC12828ACBA 14
8DG59242BAAD 43
8DG60349AAAC
8DG60565AAAG
8DG60566AAAF 25
8DG60568AAAC
8DG60912AAAF 6
8DG62635AAAC
```

There's nothing special going on - this technique is frequently used by those who use `awk` frequently, especially when processing multiple files, and it is based on the idea of loading information from first file into array.

The way this works is simple. First using `NR==FNR` ( comparison between current processed line number and line number in current file) we read everything from `file1.txt` (in OP's example that's `s2.txt` ) into associative array of values.  `next` keyword allows us to skip the next codeblock while we're still in the first file. Once we're out of the first file, the next codeblock will be executed, printing field 1 always, and corresponding item in array if it exists.

#### Perl

Using similar idea as the awk one, we can achieve similar result in Perl like so:

```
perl -lane 'if($F[1]){$hash{$F[1]}=$F[0]}else{print "$_ $hash{$_}"}' file1.txt file2.txt
```